# XHTML Markup Problems

Tags: validation, xhtml, xhtml-transitional

my template includes following:

```
      <h1 style="height: 80px;" /><img border="0" src="/somemoduledirectoryhere/Headline.ashx?c=sometexthere&amp;fc=" alt="anothertexthere" /></h1>
   <h2 style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 5px;">someheadlinehere</h2>
```

I receive following errors during XHTML 1.0 transitional markup.

document type does not allow element "h2" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag

end tag for element "h1" which is not open

Would you please suggest me how to fix these two problems?

Thank you.

Comment: well, i still have this problem because h1 tag includes only an image and alt text for it.
Should i remove h1 tag from my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're self closing the H1 tag

Remove the forward slash in:

```
<h1 style="height: 80px;" />
```

so its

```
<h1 style="height: 80px;">
```

Comment: Simon, by any chance do you like Turkish raki :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 style="height: 80px;" />
                          ^
```

Remove the self-closing tag syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In first line, you self-close `h1`:

```
<h1 style="height: 80px;" />
```

should be

```
<h1 style="height: 80px;">
```